# Overriden Event does not execute on Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I've been learning Unreal Engine through this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/185-unreal-engine-4-c-tutorial) and I am having an issue with overriding an event I created on C++ using blueprints.

So here is what I've done:

- I created a class called ABasePlayer that inherits from APawn. And I am trying to make this jump.
- On the unreal project settings > Engine > Input, I created an Action Mapping called "Jump" and set it to the space bar.
- On the ABasePlayer, I created a function called Jump, like this:

  UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent)
  void Jump();
- I also created a jump impulse property, looks like this:

  UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWRITE)
  float JumpImpulse;
- In the `SetupPlayerInputComponent` function, I added the next line :

  InputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &ABasePlayer::Jump);
- Then I went to the blueprint editor of my main player, and override the function:
  [image: overriding Jump]
- I then created the next blueprint to add Jump to my player:

[image: blueprint]

- I then added the jump impulse :

[image: jump_impulse]

-After building and compiling, I ran the scene but nothing happened. When I press space nothing happens.

So what I did next was to try to implement jump by code instead, just to see if I can see what is going wrong with my blueprint. I went to C++, and implemented the Jump function in this way:

```
void ABasePlayer::Jump() {
    
    FVector ForceToAdd = FVector(0, 0, 1) * JumpImpulse ;
    Mesh->AddForce(ForceToAdd);


    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Jump!"));


}
```

Curiously enough, whenever I press space I see the "Jump" message, but there is no jumping.

My question would be, did I did something wrong? Did I oversee something in these steps that does not allow my character to jump?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried creating the jump function in blueprint alone instead of overriding the C++ event?  What happens now?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now it is working. What happened was that I was editing the wrong BP_Player instance? When clicking on Blueprints > Open blueprint class two BP_Player appeared. I modified another one and it started to work. Once I know more about why there are 2 BP_Player blueprints I will post what happened as a solution.